Как хранить списки для каждого врача? PHP
Делаю API, и встал вопрос о том как хранить специальности и дополнительное образование врача в базе? В HTML это выводится так


                            <div class="doctor-card__about--row">
                            <div class="doctor-card__about--title">
                                Дополнительное образование:
                            </div>
                            <div class="doctor-card__about--text">
                                2020 г. Профессиональная программа "Нейрохирургия", Сертификационный курс по специальности «нейрохирургия», Российская Медицинская Академия Последипломного образования <br>
                                2017 г. Профессиональная программа "Неотложная нейрохирургия" ФГБОУ ВО МГМСУ им. Ф. И. Евдокимова Минздрава России. <br>
                                2014 г. Реабилитация пациентов с различными заболеваниями и травмами позвоночника и спинного мозга», Московский НПЦ медицинской реабилитации, восстановительной и спортивной медицины
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="doctor-card__about--row">
                            <div class="doctor-card__about--title">
                                Специализация:
                            </div>
                            <div class="doctor-card__about--text">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Лечение геморроя метолом латексного лигирования геморроидальных узлов</li>
                                    <li>Удаление хронической анальной трещины</li>
                                    <li>Современные методы консервативной терапии трещин</li>
                                    <li>Удаление тромбов из наружных геморроидальных узлов (тромбоэктопия)</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>



Вот мой метод для добавления врача, я не понимаю как тут хранить списки чтобы их можно было например через , писать в форме админки. Использую RedBean
        $additional_education = $_POST['additional_education'] ?? '';
        $specialties = $_POST['specialties'] ?? '';
        $doctor = R::dispense('doctors');
        $doctor->photo = $photo; //Фото доктора
        $doctor->fio = $fio; //ФИО доктора
        $doctor->experience_about = $experience_about; //Какой стаж
        $doctor->experience = $experience; //Стаж доктора
        $doctor->specialty = $specialty; //Специализация
        $doctor->price = $price; //Стоимось первичного приёма
        $doctor->education = $education; //Образование
        $clinic = R::load('clinics', $clinicId);
        if ($clinic->id) {
            $doctor->id_clinic = $clinic->id;
        } else {
            echo json_encode(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Клиника не найдена'], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
            exit;
        }
        $id = R::store($doctor);
        echo json_encode(['status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Доктор успешно добавлен', 'doctor_id' => $id], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);


Списки хранить в отдельных таблицах, читать про отношение многие-ко-многим и джойны. RedBean лучше не использовать

@Ипатьев чем можно заменить RedBean?

Не надо его заменять, учите SQL и PDO для начала. А потом уже будете искать себе ORM. Но к тому времени будете осваивать фреймворк, в котором будет уже свой готовый.
